# Android deep linking issue with complex URL and question symbol

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-deep-link

I'm trying to build a deep link integration for our client.
The link is similar to this: https://example.com/en/user/login?destination=user/profile-edit .

Now I know that a match with `android:path` would work but there are other language supported than `en` so we need something more dynamic - like `android:pathPattern`.

I can't make it to work though. I've tried with this:

```
android:pathPattern="/.*/.*/login?destination=user/profile-edit"
android:pathPattern="/.*/.*/.*/profile-edit"
```

but it fails. I realized that if I try the link without the `?` (like this: https://example.com/en/user/login?destination=user/profile-edit) the deep link is opened successfully. It also works if I swap the path segment with the query to be in the beginning(https://example.com/login?destination=user/en/user/profile-edit).

I tried with escaping the question mark like this as well but it was also unsuccessful:

```
android:pathPattern="/.*/.*/login\\?destination=user/profile-edit"
```

Comment: Intent filters don't support query parameters at all; it is just the path up to the query parameters that is checked

Comment: Ok but then why would https://example.com/login?destination=user/en/user/profile-edit work properly?